# JavaScript Variable Declaration

Tags: javascript

This is a really stupid question, but I'm just drawing a blank here...

What type of variable declaration is this:

```
var s1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

Also, How can I construct a variable like this from multiple objects when the amount of those objects is unknown. This is what I came up with, which doesn't work.

```
var s1 = [];
for(x in data[i].uh) {
    s1 += data[i].uh[x];
}
```

Comment: that's an array.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var s1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

is an array declaration of four integers using ["Array Literal Notation"](http://freewebdesigntutorials.com/javaScriptTutorials/jsArrayObject/declareAnArray.htm)

You don't need a loop to copy the array, simply do this:

```
var s1 = data.slice(0);
```

or in your example you might want this:

```
var s1 = data[i].uh.slice(0);
```

Read more about copying arrays here: http://my.opera.com/GreyWyvern/blog/show.dml/1725165

> "The slice(0) method means, return a
>   slice of the array from element 0 to
>   the end. In other words, the entire
>   array. Voila, a copy of the array."

Comment: Be careful with duplicating an array using slice as it is a reference copy and not a value copy. Meaning if you change one you change the other.

Comment: @The_asMan

No, it copies the array. Consider this code:         
        `var foo = [1,2,3,4,5];
        alert(foo[2]); /* Returns 3 */
        var bar = foo.slice(0);
        alert(bar[2]); /* Returns 3 */
        bar[2] = 0;
        alert(bar[2]); /* Returns 0 */
        alert(foo[2]); /* Returns 3 */`

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Answer (score 2):

That is called an `Array`, which can be declared with `new Array()` or by using the array literal `[]` as in your example.  You can use the `Array.push()` method ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2)) to add a new value to it:

```
var s1 = [];
for(x in data[i].uh) {
    s1.push(data[i].uh[x]);
}
```

Comment: Oh wow. Okay, I thought array's had to be declared with new Array().

Answer (score 2):

This

```
var s1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

is an array declaration.

To add an element to an array, use the `push` method:

```
var s1 = [];
for(x in data[i].uh) {
    s1.push(data[i].uh[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`s1` is an array, it's a proper Javascript object with functions.

```
var s1 = [];
```

is the recommend way to create an array. As opposed to:

```
var s1 = new Array();
```

(see: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays)

To add items to an array use `s1.push(item)` so your code would be:

```
var s1 = [];
for(x in data[i].uh) {
    s1.push(data[i].uh[x]);
}
```

As a side note, I wouldn't recommend using for-in, at least not without checking hasOwnProperty.

Answer (score 1):

It's declaring a local variable with an `Array` with 4 members.

If you want to append to an `Array`, use the `push()` method.

Answer (score 1):

That is an array.  To add to arrays you would use Array.push(). For example:

```
var s1 = [];
s1.push(1);
s1.push(2);
```